# Split arrays based on sequences javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array like

```
var arr = [12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

I was wondering how I could iterate through the array so that I can split this array into 2 arrays based on the sequences ? i.e. basically if `i+1 != true` make it a new array

```
var arr = [12, 13, 14]
var arr2 = [17,18,19,20]
```

I am using lodash and have tried a number of `for` statements using `splice` but Im getting a bit confused ? Appreciate any help

Comment: little more information please how you want to split - the split after 3 elements is pretty easy, is that all you need?

Comment: 2 arrays with equals half?

Comment: I need the split to recognize when the sequence has stopped ? i.e. 12, 13, 14 - then there is a break and the sequence doesnt start again until 17, 18, 19. i.e. `i+1 != true split to new array` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a another, more dense approach, which uses underscore's quite convenient [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) and [values](http://underscorejs.org/#values) methods:

```
var origin = [12,13,14,15,17,18,19,21,22,23];
var c = 0, result = _.values( _.groupBy(origin, function(el, i, arr) { 
  return i ? c+= (1 !== el - arr[i-1]) : 0; }) );
```

As a result, `result` archive will contain all the sequences as elements. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynkpu/) to play with.

Explanation: `groupBy` groups the source array with help of the callback (which returns a new sequence number each time the difference between the currently processed element (`el`) and the previous one (`arr[i-1]`) is bigger than 1. It returns an object, though, so I have to put it through `_.values`; you may or may not this step.

*I wonder is that possible to request something like `groupByInArray` function? Should be trivial to implement, but might be very useful in situations like this.*

Comment: great! thanks heaps. yeah i think something like groupBy would be great. I even have a scenario like `[[12, 0], [13, 0], [14, 0], [18,0], [19,1], [20,0]]` where I need to split this too ? So its like `[[12, 0], [13, 0], [14, 0]]` and `[[18,0], [19,1], [20,0]]`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can reuse this function with a minor change: replace checking `el - arr[i-1]` with `el[0] - arr[i-1][0]`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aL8ht/)

Comment: yeah awesome! thanks heaps. I was just wondering I mean if you had a `groupByInArray` that it would also support these scenarios too! Would be an unreal add to underscore lib

Comment: I meant pull request to Underscore library itself.

Comment: ahh, i didn´t even know something like this existed, sounds and looks just like haskell (at least a little), loving it :)

Answer (score 3):

[**Example on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PHAYD/)

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7];

var r = [];
var t = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        t.push(a[i]); // add the first element and continue
        continue;
    }
    if (a[i - 1] != (a[i] - 1))
    {
        // if the current is not sequential
        // add the current temporary array to arrays result
        r.push(t);

        // clear the temporary array and start over
        t = [];
    }

    t.push(a[i]);
}
r.push(t);
```

`r` will contain all your arrays

[**Minified version**](http://jsfiddle.net/bdueA/)

```
function seq(e,t,n,r){t=[];n=[];for(r=0;r<e.length;++r){if(!r){n.push(e[r]);continue}if(e[r-1]!=e[r]-1){t.push(n);n=[]}n.push(e[r])}t.push(n);return t}

var result = seq([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XM298/)?

```
function split(arr) {
    var res = [];
    var subres = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var length = subres.length;
        if (length === 0 || subres[length - 1] === arr[i] - 1) {
            subres.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            res.push(subres);
            subres = [arr[i]];
        }
    }
    res.push(subres);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: yes! thanks a lot. im not sure if this can be made faster using lodash or underscore if you are familiar with those ?

Comment: @Andy using either library would not make anything faster.

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
var array = [12,13,14,4567,789,0]; //e.g.
var index;
var previous = array[0];
for (var index = 1; index++; index < array.length) {
  if (previous + 1 == array[index]) {
    previous = array[index]; //++
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
var firstPart = array.slice(0, index + 1);
var secondPart = array.slice(index + 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zajnH/